# How much increment when I am firing a ball?

Tags: c++, geometry

I hope all of you are doing fine :-)
I have got a ball shooter game project (This is the first time I am developing a game on C++ after 4 months of starting C++).

The issue I have is, I want to fire a ball exactly towards the mouse direction so I can strike the top balls. How much increment should I do on the y and x coordinates of the ball, since it is totally dependent on direction?

What I have now is the coordinates of the mouse, the coordinates of the stick and the coordinates of the bottom line. The formula I was thinking was `y=(slope)x+c slope=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)`. I am confused. I tried this and I don't know what c is. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The vector which goes from one point to another is obtained by computing the difference between the two vectors pointing to each of the two points. If your coordinate system has its origin at `(0,0)`, then the vector pointing to the point `(a,b)` is simply the vector `(a,b)`. Finding the "direction" from `(a,b)` to `(c,d)`, you need to calculate `(c,d) - (a,b) = (c-a,d-b)`.

You can then normalize this vector, to get a normalized direction vector, onto which you can apply a scale factor to control the speed of movement. The position of your ball is then updated as:

`p2 = p1 + d * dt`

where `p1=(x,y)` is the vector representing the position at time `t`; `p2` is the vector representing the position at time `t+dt`; `d` is the normalized direction vector (see above); and `dt` is the elapsed time since last update (the time step).